# Exception while opening MPart if progress bar is displaying in Eclipse E4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In eclipse E4, I am trying to open a MPart under progress dialog(i.e. Progress bar will be displayed untill Mpart will not display/load the contents), but i am getting below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getActiveWindowService(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getParts(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getParts(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:92)
    at com.gui.common.utils.ViewUtils.createPart(ViewUtils.java:549)
    ... 49 more
```

Below is the code i am using to open the MPart:
            IEclipseContext serviceContext = E4Workbench.getServiceContext();
            final IEclipseContext appContext = (IEclipseContext) serviceContext
                    .getActiveChild(); //$NON-NLS-1$

```
        EModelService modelService = appContext.get(EModelService.class);
        MApplication app = serviceContext.get(MApplication.class);
        EPartService partService = serviceContext.get(EPartService.class);
        MPerspective activePerspective = modelService
                .getActivePerspective(app.getSelectedElement());
        List<MPartStack> stacks = modelService.findElements(
                activePerspective, null, MPartStack.class, null,
                EModelService.IN_ACTIVE_PERSPECTIVE);
        List<MPart> parts = modelService.findElements(
                activePerspective, null, MPart.class, null,
                EModelService.IN_ACTIVE_PERSPECTIVE);

        MPartStack stack = null;
        for (MPartStack foundStack : stacks) {
            if (foundStack.getElementId().indexOf(stackType) >= 0) {
                stack = foundStack;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (stack != null) {
            MPart part = null;
            // Create a new Part

            String viewIDtoDisplay = null;
            if(secondaryID!=null){
                viewIDtoDisplay=viewID + RvsConstants.COLON + secondaryID;
            }else{
                viewIDtoDisplay=viewID;
            }
            for (MPart openedParts : parts) {
                if (openedParts.getElementId().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        viewIDtoDisplay)) {
                    part = openedParts;
                }
            }
            if (part == null) {
                part = modelService.createModelElement(MPart.class);
                part.setElementId(viewIDtoDisplay);
                part.setContributionURI(COMPATIBILITY_VIEW);
                part.setCloseable(true);
                if (isClosable) {
                    part.getTags().add(REMOVE_ON_EXIT);
                }
                part.getTags().add(EPartService.REMOVE_ON_HIDE_TAG);
                MElementContainer<MUIElement> parent = null;
                for (MStackElement element : stack.getChildren()) {
                    if (element instanceof MPlaceholder) {
                        MPlaceholder holder = (MPlaceholder) element;
                        if (holder.getRef().getElementId()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(viewID)) {
                            holder.setWidget(part);
                            parent = holder.getParent();

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (parent != null) {
                    part.setParent(parent);
                }

            }

            partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE); // Show part
            ViewReference ref = ((WorkbenchPage) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage())
                    .getViewReference(part);
            IViewPart viewRef = ref.getView(true);
```

This is not a pure E4 application and i am using Compat layer.
If i am not using progress bar, the exception never occurs and Mpart opens smoothly. So is there any way to open Mpart if progress bar is displaying.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Could you please provide us with some code? It is hard to establish where is the problem without actually looking at what you've coded.

Comment: Looks like you are using the `EPartService` for the application, you probably need to be using the `EPartService` for the current window.

Comment: @greg-449, the problem is I am trying to open list of MPart in a job, and we have a requirement that in first 2 second progress bar should not displayed. So the above exception occurs when progress bar is displaying in the application(i.e after 2 seconds), so could you please guide me how can i make sure that i am using current window EpartService as in the flow i can not predict when progress bar will be displaying

Comment: @greg-449, how can i get the current part service in application, it seems this can be the solution?

Comment: You can use `getActiveLeaf()` on the app context to get the active context and get the service from the context. But this is more or less what the application part service is trying to do.

Comment: What I do is use a `ProgressMonitorPart` as a control in the `MPart` to show progress during initialization.

Comment: @greg-449, As progress bar is used to execute a job which is responsible for creating multiple views at a time, So i am not sure how can i use ProgressMonitorPart. Could you please guide me with small snippet? Also is there any other way to open view without using partService in this case as I am getting error while opening the view in below line
            partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);